# How do I design an algorithm to find the biggest number in a list of numbers?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I also need to convert my answer into javascript code that displays the largest value.

Comment: So, are you asking about algorithm design or about javascript code?

Comment: There's a difference between "this is not a good question" and "this is not a question". The asker wants an algorithm for finding the max element in a list, and wants to write it in JavaScript. Downvoting I understand, but closing seems a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: Well he still got his answer, didn't he? The two answers below work fine.

Comment: @John - I agree.  Although it seems like untagged homework help to me.

Comment: I don't know why people close questions so quickly. Even they did not give time to edit the question and add more details.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(Math.max(13, 42, 86, 3, 25)); // 86
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need something on the lines of:

```
var mx = list[0];
for (i=1; i<length(list); i++)
    mx = Math.max(mx, list[i])

alert(mx)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Math.max.apply(null, list)`